# I get "EOS" error with stylus when compiling with grunt-contrib-stylus

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, stylus, eoserror

I keep getting this weird error message when compiling. Very hard to debug.
(By the way: opacity in the example is a mixin)

But I'm stuck on

```
> 59| .red { opacity 0.4 }

expected "indent", got "eos"
```

I've tried

```
.red { opacity(0.4) }
.red { opacity(0.4); }
```

and nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problem A

The issue is that for some syntax reasons, stylus doesn't permit mixins alone in a selector

## The solution(s)

1. is to use multi line

   ```
   .red {
        opacity(0.4);
   }
   ```
2. add a bogus property (make sure it doesn't affect your styling)

   ```
   .red { opacity(0.4); zoom:1; }
   ```

---

## Problem B

Another issue was with reset styles, being without a new line between them.

```
body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none} ...
```

## The solution

To put each of the style on individual lines:

```
body{line-height:1}
ol,ul{list-style:none}
blockquote,q{quotes:none}
...
```

---

Very very weird issues and even weirder solution :P

Hope that this save some of your time (because I've wasted a lot of mine on this :( ).

Answer (score 17):

I've also found that you can get this error if you mix spaces and tabs. It's a strange error to get for this issue. Just make sure that you stick with one or the other.

Comment: Good stuff. Just to add to this, all my files broke when I added syntax specific options into Sublime Text. Having `translate_tabs_to_spaces` set to false was the culprit.

Comment: A tip if using vim, you can see hidden characters with :list

Answer (score 9):

I found this was caused by an erroneous curly brace left behind when conversing css or a mixin

```
myMixin(var = 1){  <--- nooooooo
  color red
  etc etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. As it turns out, this problem can also be caused if you have two consecutive, adjacent hashes when defining a color:

```
color #FFF  <- good

color ##FFF  <- easy to miss, will cause very unhelpful 'eos' message at file end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and (after about 30 min) realized it was an extra opening brace that my IDE put in - clearly I should have been watching more carefully!  I would suggest looking at all your git (or what have you) changes very carefully and be sure you have no double opening braces:

```
.class-name-of-greatness {
{ 
   color: blue;
   border: gold
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For all the Vi(m) users: Can also be triggered by

```
$width--s = 24rem:wq
```

(last 3 chars)